# Wordpress Table Won't Update after AJAX / PHP (even with 200 ok response)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

This is my first attempt at trying to update a database with ajax & wordpress. I am trying to set a field to a status of 'complete' when a link is clicked. Everything seems to go fine, I get a "200 ok" response from the console, and the jQuery even shows the success actions that I'm taking. However the php doesn't update the database. The proper variables are being echoed out to the console, so I know those are being set correctly. I don't know if it's my MySQL query that I'm trying or if there's something that I'm overlooking. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my jQuery:

```
// Click to Complete Activity Functionality
jQuery(".complete-activity").click( function( e ) {  
    e.preventDefault();   
    nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")  
    wp_user_id = jQuery(this).attr("wp_user_id")
    activity_post_id = jQuery(this).attr("activity_post_id")

    wp_user_id = parseInt(wp_user_id);
    activity_post_id = parseInt(activity_post_id);

    console.log('My wp user id is: ' + wp_user_id);
    console.log('My Activity id is: ' + activity_post_id);

  jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
     data : {
         action: "gw_complete_activity", 
         "wp_user_id" : wp_user_id, 
         "activity_post_id" : activity_post_id,
         "nonce" : nonce
         },
     success: function(response) {    
            console.log('Your field has been set as completed');
            jQuery('li#active-'+ activity_post_id).css('display', 'none'); 

     }
  })   

}) // End click to complete activity
```

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
//Complete Activity in Database (AJAX)
add_action("wp_ajax_gw_complete_activity", "gw_complete_activity");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_gw_complete_activity", "my_must_login_to_complete");

function gw_complete_activity() {

   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "gw_complete_activity")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
   }   

   $wp_user_id = $_REQUEST['wp_user_id'];
   $activity_post_id_complete = $_REQUEST['activity_post_id'];
   $date_completed = current_time('mysql', 1);
   global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->update ( 
    'wp_gwactivities', 
    array( 'date_completed' => $date_completed, 'activity_status' => 'complete'), 
    array( 'wp_user_id' => $wp_user_id)
);


if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  $result_add = json_encode($result_add);
    echo $result_add;
 }
   else {
     header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);  
  }


  die();

}

function my_must_login_to_complete() {
   echo "You must be logged in to complete your activities.";
  die();
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you get a 200 (OK) from the requested page, doesn't mean the requested page didn't error out :) Secondly, it looks like this is  going to be used in Wordpress... with that said, you can't use `add_action` without having wordpress loaded.

For files outside the normal wordpress install, you need to include wp-load.php `include "/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php"`, for example. Then you can use its functions.

Comment: The link that initiates the ajax is in a page-template within my wordpress theme. The jQuery file, and the php that has the SQL statement in it is in a plugin folder. So with the plugin running, wouldn't wp-load already have been called?

Comment: Remember, servers are stateless. If you're only calling that ajax file (and that ajax file isn't including anything WP-related), then it won't work. Just because the caller is running in WP, doesn't mean the callee will be.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me on this. I tried that and it's still not working. It's weird because I have an almost identical file that inserts into the database successfully in the same folder as this one. The only difference is the names of the actions and the sql query.

Comment: Turn error_reporting on, then monitor your console and/or network tab in firebug or whatever browser debugger you're using.

Comment: Ok, after changing the success message to alert the data, I get my message of, "No naughty business please", which is shown when the nonce isn't verified. I'm looking through it but nothing is sticking out at me...

Answer (score 0):

After your update query ,put below code and check query in mysql directly.

```
print_r($wpdb->last_query);
```

provide your query here also if its not work.

Comment: This is a beginner's question but with it being ajax, do I have to modify where it will print this out?

Comment: It will print in console.